# TFDManager v/s FDManager function vs TFDCustomManager

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I read some of the documentation on TFDManager and TFDCustomManager but none of it explained the difference between them properly. Can someone please help me understand the difference between TFDManager v/s FDManager function vs TFDCustomManager and which is recommended for use in the app.

Comment: `TFDManager` inherits directly from `TFDCustomManager` and it just reintroduces some of its properties with `published` visibility. This is a common technique for component developers to create their own implementations of custom components. I guess you aren't developing your own connection manager, therefore you can ignore this fact and just use [`FDManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.FDManager) singleton instance as documented.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.programmersought.com/article/80106275092/